# What is the max number of user a User Field Type (Mult="TRUE") can handle?

Tags: column

I am using `SharePoint standard 2010`. Does anyone know how many users we can store in a `User` field, when we have attribute `Mult="TRUE"`? Is there any limit?

I have looked around, and found nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [msdn article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Column), 96 is the limit for column type people/group.

[image]

Comment: The limit type is Threshold which is "... Configurable limits that can be exceeded to accommodate specific requirements"

Comment: That is just the number of columns you can have, not the number of people in the column, that's what he is wanting to know

Comment: @PirateEric Totally agree, I also found this article, but does not answer my question.

Comment: I don't know what the bound is, I don't know if it's been tested, most I've personally seen is about 20